# Несколько запросов в рамках одной сессии

Tags: java

Как можно из java делать несколько пост запрос в одной сессии. Сейчас я открываю коннекцию (`url.openConnection()`) делаю запрос, открываю еще одну коннекцию так как уже адрес другой, хотя сайт тот же, просто на другую страницу. Как мне можно делать несколько запрос в одной сессии на разные страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для поддержания сессии между запросами вам нужно зарегистрировать глобальный `CookieManager`.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();  
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Comment: Если это устанавливаю тогда пишет Server returned http response code 500 for url, а если не устанавливаю куки, тогда возвращает json, в чем может быть дело